# Cakephp 2.5. : how to use html tags and autoLinkUrls in this case

Tags: html, cakephp, text, helper

I have a text part like this:

```
<p><?php echo __('<strong>some strong text</strong> some other text  THIS IS AN URL more other text <strong>more strong text</strong> and finally end of text'); ?></p>
```

I wonder what would be the best way to:

- use html tags in such text lines (as I need to use i18n translations)
- how can I add an url in the middel of the text?

When setting the URL I would also like to use the Cake Style of `$this->Html->Link()` but I don't know how I can do this in this example above?

Answer (score 3):

[Read the manual.](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#using-variables-in-translation-messages)

> Using Variables in Translation Messages
>   Translation functions allow you to interpolate variables into the messages using special markers defined in the message itself or in the translated string:

```
echo __("Hello, my name is {0}, I'm {1} years old", ['Sara', 12]);
```

---

Just generate your link `$link = $this->Html->link(__('foo'), [/*...*/]);` and pass $link to the __() functions 2nd arg as shown in the example above.

Read the whole section about the translations functions, there are a few more good to know things like plural / singular and number handling.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the example. Is it possible to add a link this way?
__('this is my <link text>', ['link text', 'http://www...'])

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it.

```
<p>
    <?php 
         $string = '<strong>some strong text</strong> some other text ';
         $string .= 'https://www.example.com';
         $string .= ' more other text <strong>more strong text</strong> and finally <b>end of text</b>';
         echo $this->Html->link(__($string),'http://www2.test.com',['escape'=>false]); 
     ?>
</p>
```